# When should I close the cursor that I supply to ListView

Tags: android

I supply a cursor to a ListActivity like this:  My question is how/when should I close my cursor when I am done?

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(this, cursor);
            setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onDestroy()`. Sooner, if you are specifically clearing out the list sooner than that. Or, call `startManagingCursor(cursor)`, and Android will close it for you, when it is safe to do so.

Comment: What should I do in my onDestory() to close the cursor that I passe to CursorAdpater()?  Or I have to keep a reference to getContentResolover().query() myself and call 'close()' in the onDestory() manually? 

Thank you.

Comment: @michael: If you are using `getContentResolver().query()`, that `Cursor` is already managed, and so you do not need to close it yourself, as Android will close it for you. I apologize -- I was focused on the cursor and did not realize you had gotten it from a `ContentResolver` instead of SQLite.

Comment: @CommonsWare: If I put the `cursor.close()` line in `onDestroy`, cursor will be closed each time device orientation changes and that's undesirable. What can I do in that case?

Comment: @alireza: Have the `Cursor` be managed by a retained fragment, then `close()` the `Cursor` in the fragment's `onDestroy()`. Or, if the `Cursor` is coming from a `ContentProvider`, use `CursorLoader` to query the provider, as you will not need to `close()` the `Cursor` yourself, and it will be provided to your new activity instance after the configuration change.